# Creating a web application firewall with nodejs

Tags: apache2, web-application-firewall

I want view if someone try to inject xss,sql to my apache2 server, My idea is create a waf in nodejs and if the connection is secure, redirect to apache2. It is posible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's certainly possible, but avoid the term "redirect" here. What you really want is to a reverse proxy. There's no shortage of basic examples of a node.js reverse proxy -- you'll just need to add whatever WAF checks prior to proxying.